# Sort directory in DOS and grab first n files

Tags: for-loop, dos

I need to sort a directory alphabetically and then grab the first n files in the folder. This is all in DOS.

I was using this as a start:

for %a in (*.tif) do (

bla bla

)

NOTE: all files in directory are .tif

BUT this will grab all the files, I don't know how to specify only to grab first n files (n=13). Any suggestions??? THANK YOU I really can't figure this one out!

Comment: when you *grab* them, what do you do with them?

Comment: move them to a different folder

Comment: Into an empty folder?

Comment: yes into an empty folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way.

```
@echo off
set "target=d:\tif files"
md "%target%" 2>nul
for %%a in (*.tif) do (
dir "%target%\*.tif" /b |find /c /v ""|findstr "^13$">nul && goto :done
move "%%a" "%target%">nul
)
:done
```

Comment: thanks! I had to modify some stuff to make it work but in the end got the program working like it should. Cheers :)

Comment: You can also use a variable and count up with each file moved.  That's more efficient.